# Java Spring, getMapping return folder of files

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to retrieve a folder of files from my Java Spring backend but cant figure out the correct way. What am I doing wrong?

I have managed to retrieve a single file like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(value = "gallery/test", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {


        return IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass()
            .getResourceAsStream("/gallery/test/images.jpg"));
    }
```

And have tried to modify the code so that it should return an ArrayList of the type Byte

```
private static File[] getResourceFolderFiles (String folder) {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL url = loader.getResource(folder);
        String path = url.getPath();
        return new File(path).listFiles();

...

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(value = "gallery/test", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    ArrayList<byte[]> getImage() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<byte[]> files = new ArrayList();

        for (File f : getResourceFolderFiles("/gallery/test/")) {
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            files.add(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass()
                    .getResourceAsStream(f.getAbsolutePath())));
        }
        return files;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the HTTP response to contain, specifically?

Comment: I was hoping I could send some sort of byte-array with all images in the folder. If not possible how should I configure the mapping so that the frontend can get all images in that folder?

Comment: You'd have to provide your own `HttpMessageConverter` for `ArrayList<byte[]>` and find a way to serialize all that to the response (with proper delimiters). You'd also have to implement a client to understand that serialization. The proper way to do this is for your client to somehow find a list of all the images and generate links for each one individually. Your server should serve them individually.

Comment: Ok, is that the standard way of handeling folders ? or is there any way to do this more easily?